# Definition of validation loss

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm reading the paper [The Lottery Hypothesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03635). In this paper, they're using as early stopping criterium "minimum validation loss".

While they even have an appendix explaining what is meant by that... it doesn't seem to explain it for me at all.

As far as I understood, a low validation loss means that the generalization capability of the model to the test set is good.

What's the precise definition of "validation loss"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Validation loss" is the loss calculated on the validation set, when the data is split to train / validation / test sets using [cross-validation](/questions/tagged/cross-validation). The idea is that you have three, separate sets of data: one used for training the model (*train*), one for doing things like hyperparameter tuning, model selection (*validation*), and one used to make final check of the model (*test*). The [test set is held-out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237790/why-cant-i-use-test-set-as-validation-set), so you don't use it for making any adjustments to the model, you use it only to calculate the final metrics.

Comment: So the validation loss is the percentage of incorrectly classified labels by the neural network for the validation set?

Comment: @Sudix "percentage of incorrectly classified labels" only if they used 1 - accuracy as a loss function, but there are also other loss functions, e.g. mean squared error, or cross-entropy etc.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll have to look through their code base to find the loss function they used

Comment: Related: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/37409/2853